# C++ reference to C string is possible?

Tags: c++

In recompiling our large legacy app with g++ 4.8.2 (32-bit std=C++98), a new warning popped out from part of the data serializer saying `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]`

The code compiled without warning on g++ 4.4.7.

The warning comes from a templated function serializing a "char &", where the comments say it is a reference to a null-terminated string.

I'm new to C++... isn't `const char&` a reference to a single character? And wouldn't using that reference as the start address of a C null-terminated string be some kind of cheat?

Do I ignore the warning, or otherwise, what is the appropriate form (if any) for this construct?

```
//! Implementations of write() for null-terminated strings.
void write(DvCsr::TName, const char*    v, long = NO_INDEX) {writeCStr(v);}
void write(DvCsr::TName, const u_char*  v, long = NO_INDEX) {writeCStr(v);}
void write(DvCsr::TName, const char&    v, long = NO_INDEX) {writeRefCStr(v);}
void write(DvCsr::TName, const u_char&  v, long = NO_INDEX) {writeRefCStr(v);}

//! Write null-terminated string data types to the stream.
template <class T>
void writeCStr(const T* start)
{
    // Find length of the string, not including null terminator,
    // and size (in bytes), including null terminator.
    const T* end = start;
    while (*end++)
        ;
    size_t len = end - start;

    // Add the string to the end of the buffer.
    mBuffer.reserve(mBuffer.size() + len);
    std::copy(start, start + len, std::back_inserter(mBuffer));
};

template <class T>
void writeRefCStr(const T &start)
{
    writeCStr((unsigned char *)start);
}
```

Comment: Good rule of thumb: Never ignore warnings and always compile with `-pedantic -Wall`

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'd add `-Wextra` to that (as a minimum).

Comment: @JesperJuhl In that case, I would also add `-pedantic-errors -Werror` :P

Answer (score 1):

I see two basic problems. First you are casting the single character to a pointer, you need to take its address `&start`. Second you are casting from a `const&` to a non const pointer which can give undefined behavior.

```
template <class T>
void writeRefCStr(const T& start)
{
    // use &start to obtain its address
    //
    // use reinterpret_cast so the compiler complains about the
    // lack of const (and make it a const unsigned char*)
    //
    writeCStr(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&start));
}
```

The so-called "c-style-cast" aka `(unsigned char*)` removes all compiler warnings so it the `C++` casts like [reintrpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
// Definition
void write(DvCsr::TName, const char&    v, long = NO_INDEX) {writeRefCStr(v);}

// Call
void writeRefCStr(const T &start){
    writeCStr((unsigned char *)start);
}
```

You are using the **value** of `start` to write. Instead you should

```
    writeCStr((unsigned char *) &start);
                                ^
```

... so that you're using the **address** of `start` to write.

**Reference** is essentially an unchangeable **alias** for an existing object. You don't get its address when something is passed as a reference. You're getting itself. You should use the address operator `&` on your reference.

Comment: This will not make the character magically be null-terminated though, so there is still a problem.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Let's assume the OP is calling the function correctly.

Comment: That's a false assumption, because we see how the functions are called (the first four lines excluding comments), and they are *not* called with a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with one character string you need to allocate a two char buffer to make sure it's null-terminated.

void writeRefCStr(const T &start){
    const char tmp[2]={start, 0};
    writeCStr(tmp); // tmp is the same as const char*
}